# How to center UISegmentControl in a toolbar at top of UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've seen a few different posts on this, but I can't seem to get it working.  I basically have a UITableView and want sort buttons at the top of a popover controller.  I followed this post: [UIPopoverController toolbar at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599918/uipopovercontroller-toolbar-at-top) in order to get started.  In my controller that is the rootViewController of the navigationController, I can create a UISegmentControl and place it at the top.  However, it does not look like the picture in that it's not centered.  Maybe because the way I get it into the popover is in the viewDidLoad of the popover like this:

```
   UISegmentedControl *topSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil]];
    topSegmentControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    topSegmentControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    UIBarButtonItem *toolBarCustom = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:topSegmentControl];
//    UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = toolBarCustom;
```

Also, if I want to present data at the bottom of the popovercontroller in a toolbar, I'm not sure where to do that.  Following the same example: [UIPopoverController toolbar at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599918/uipopovercontroller-toolbar-at-top), I thought in my navigationController, I would do something like this:

```
 UISegmentedControl *topSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"BottomOne", @"BottomTwo", @"BottomThree", nil]];
//    topSegmentControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    topSegmentControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    UIBarButtonItem *toolBarCustom = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:topSegmentControl];
    UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceItem, toolBarCustom, spaceItem, nil];
    [navController setToolbarItems:toolBarCustom];
    [navController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

When I try this, I see a toolBar with nothing in it, that is a lighter tint than the rest of the popover.

To summarize, I'm not sure as to where you would initialize toolbar or barbuttonitems for a popover that has a navigationcontroller like in the example.  I'm also not sure how to center the data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll probably be best suited by just setting your UISegmentedControl as the `titleView` of your root view controller’s `navigationItem`.

Comment: But UIBarButtonItem is not a child of UIView.

Comment: You don’t need to make a UIBarButtonItem for it. Literally just set `self.navigationItem.titleView = topSegmentControl`.